# Java cannot find interface in endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, endpoint

I am trying to expose the methods in a device as a web service using an endpoint in Java. The problem is that when creating the endpoint I need to pass in an instance of the implementation of the interface that defines the class but then the interface is not found on the computer that I am loading the device on. For example:

```
Endpoint anEndpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldImpl", new HelloWorldImpl());
```

But then the interface that HelloWorldImpl implements is not found.

The other classes are

```
package application;

@WebService
public interface IHelloWorld{
    @WebMethod
    public void speak();
}
```

the implementation is:

```
package application;

@WebService(EndpointInterface="application.IHelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl extends ClassForDeviceInteraction implements IHelloWorld{

    @Override
    public void speak(){
        //code that prints to a controller on the device
    }

    public void initialize(){
        //code that initializes stuff for the device
        Endpoint anEndpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/
        HelloWorldImpl", new HelloWorldImpl()); 

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        //code to initialize the device
    }
}
```

It compiles fine on my computer but when I put it on the device I get an error that says the interface `IHelloWorld` cannot be found. I haven't been able to find anything similar on Stack Overflow.

What could be the cause of the error? Is there a way to declare the interface in the class I am passing into the endpoint and then reference it in the "EndpointInterface" field?

Comment: Which web framework are you using?  (Glassfish, JBoss/Wildfly, etc...?)

Comment: I am using Jax-ws.